# if i enter any subdomain it redirects me to the maindomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, subdomain, zone

**Hi there**

i have a domain ( [iqcommunity.net](http://iqcommunity.net) ) and 1 subdomain ( [alhasaniq.iqcommunity.net](http://alhasaniq.iqcommunity.net) )
the sub domain ( [alhasaniq.iqcommunity.net](http://alhasaniq.iqcommunity.net) ) works perfectly .

but if i enter something like ( [blablabla.iqcommunity.net](http://blablabla.iqcommunity.net) ) it will redirect me to my maindomain

this is my config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName iqcommunity.net
    ServerAdmin SoljaIQ@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/subdomains/alhasaniq/
    ServerName alhasaniq.iqcommunity.net

    <Directory /path/html/alhasaniq>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-logfile.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-logfile.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit :

Solved this ( thanks to martialdidit ) By :

- **Removing my "CNAME"** Wildcard Entry in the DNS Zone file
- **Re-Entering my subdomains** each as **an "A" Entry** in the DNS Zone file

Comment: i don't think it's coming from apache

Comment: do you mean its the dns ?

Comment: this is my zone file http://puu.sh/bRROB/a19736436a.png

Comment: The third line give you the answer. `*` mean everyword